# How to create nested for loop for a certain range

Tags: r, for-loop, nested

I am looking to add rows to my data frame over a range of numbers.

I'm not great at loops so take a look if it helps:

```
k=1
for (i in 1:nrow(Data)){
  for (l in 1: Data[i,2]){
    for (j in 1: Data[i,5]){
      Data[k,]<-Data[i,]
      Data[k,3]<-Data[i,3]+j-1
      k=k+1}
  }
}
```

Here is a sample dataframe:

```
Data<- data.frame(matrix(NCOs = 4, nrow = 2))
x <- c("gid","did", "pid","plays")
colnames(Data) <- x
Data[1,]<-c(1,1,2,8)
Data[2,]<-c(1,2,12,6)
```

Output should have a total of 14 rows and looks like this

```
1 1 2 8
1 1 3 8
1 1 4 8
.
.
.
.
1 2 12 6
1 2 13 6
.
.
1 2 17 6
```

Comment: Nested for loops is a bad way to add rows to a data frame. Can you describe in words what you are trying to do, and we can help you do it in a better way?

Comment: For instance, if the starting PID is 2, and there are 8 plays, I would like to add 7 new rows to the data frame, each with an increasing PID number from 2 through 9. This needs to be done for each DID (unique).

Comment: With `dplyr` and `tidyr`: `df %>% group_by(did) %>% mutate(pid = list(seq(pid, length.out = plays))) %>% unnest()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe `tidyr::complete` is a good choice here.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

Data %>%
  group_by(gid, did) %>%
  complete(pid = seq(pid, pid + plays - 1)) %>%
  fill(plays)

#     gid   did   pid plays
#   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1     1     1     2     8
# 2     1     1     3     8
# 3     1     1     4     8
# 4     1     1     5     8
# 5     1     1     6     8
# 6     1     1     7     8
# 7     1     1     8     8
# 8     1     1     9     8
# 9     1     2    12     6
#10     1     2    13     6
#11     1     2    14     6
#12     1     2    15     6
#13     1     2    16     6
#14     1     2    17     6
```

Comment: Perfect. Thanks so much- I'll be sure to verify the answer in a few minutes.